# Sort differing date formats in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database in which a report is pulled and displayed based on city and state. There is a form where the user selects city and state and a query is run, then a report displayed based on that query. I want to sort the data from the query by Warranty Start date(WSD) then Model #. The problem is that all of the dates aren't in the same format and if I try to format the  WSD column as a date field Access Deletes at least 1000 records.  Currently all fields are formatted as short text. Is there a way that I can sort the data by date without the format being the same for all? I have attached a screenshot of some records to show the issue.

[image: Access Example]

If you need the sql query I can provide that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to sort by the date, then you can use:

```
IIf(IsDate([WSD]), CDate([WSD]), DateSerial(Val([WSD]),1,1)) AS WarrantyDate
```